# how to skip blank files in read.table() in R

Tags: r, read.table

I want to read a lot of text files in a folder using read.table in R, but there are some blank file among those text files, errors coms when I using the following code.

```
filenames<-list.files("M:/files/test1",pattern=".txt");
datalist<-lapply(filenames,function(name){
  read.table(paste("M:/files/test1/",name,sep=""),head=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep="\t")
})
```

Comment: Thank you!! Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly! The text file exists, but the content of text file is blank. I just wonder how can I skip these type of blank files when I using read.table

Comment: ' Error in read.table(way, head = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "\t") : '
  no lines available in input @Pascal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a simple error-catching mechanism using `try`:

```
datalist<-lapply(filenames,function(name){
  x <- try(read.table(paste("M:/files/test1/",name,sep=""),head=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep="\t"))
  if(inherits(x, "try-error"))
    return(NULL)
  else
    return(x)
})
```

To see this in action, try a toy example. What `try` does is return the object, or in the event of an error a special object class containing details of the error:

```
x <- try(stop("Test error"))
inherits(x, "try-error")
x
# [1] "Error in try(stop(\"Test error\")) : Test error\n"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "try-error"
# attr(,"condition")
# <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): Test error>
```

Versus if you simply introduce an error without `try` the program will stop and `x` will be undefined:

```
rm(x)
x <- stop("Test error")
# Error: Test error
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

If the operation succeeds inside `try()`, it simply returns the correct object:

```
x <- try(1)
x
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 3):

skip empty files

test the size of each file， and skip the file size of 0

```
for (file in list.files(,"*.txt")){
    if (file.size(file) == 0) next
    print(file)
}
```

Comment: This results in error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`